# Windows Service with Topshelf on .Net Core that also has a Kestrel API - Dependency Injection Issues

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, topshelf, kestrel

we are having some issues migrating some of our Windows Services from Framework to .Net Core 3.1.

The issue we are struggling with most at the moment is because we are effectively having 2 levels of dependency injection; one at the Topshelf service level, and one at the Topshelf.AfterStartingService/Kestrel API level.

This means that when we are hitting ServiceA controller with services registered in ServiceA, there is an error saying it is unable to resolve IPackageRegistrationService

Is there a better design pattern to this that we are missing? Is there a way of passing these dependencies into the Common.Startup class, without having a circular dependency from the Common project back to ServiceA?

The error looks like

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ServiceA.Console.Registration.Service.IPackageRegistrationService' while attempting to activate 'ServiceA.Console.Registration.Controllers.PackageRegistrationController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)

ServiceA.Main() registers all dependencies like so

```
private static void Main()
        {
            DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);

            var configuration = ConfigurationManager.InitialiseConfigurationBuilder().Build();
            var mainRabbitQueue = new MonitoredMessageQueue(new RabbitMessageQueue());

            // Dependency Injection
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                // Services
                .AddTransient<IReprocessExecuter, ReprocessExecuter>()
                .AddTransient<IFileNameBuilder, FileNameBuilder>()
                .AddTransient<IRuleRunner, RuleRunner>()
                .AddTransient<ITimeReporter, TimeReporter>()
                .AddTransient<IPackageRegistrationService, PackageRegistrationService>()

                .AddTransient<NetCore.Console.Common.ServiceHost<BatchProcessorService>, NetCore.Console.Common.ServiceHost<BatchProcessorService>>()

                // Console.Common
                .AddSingleton<IMessageQueue>(mainRabbitQueue)
                .AddSingleton<IMessageQueueStats>(mainRabbitQueue)
                .AddSingleton<IServiceLogger>(new ServiceEventLogger(mainRabbitQueue))
                .AddTransient<IHeartBeatService, HeartBeatService>()
                .AddTransient<IStatusService, StatusService>()

                .BuildServiceProvider();                      


            using (var serviceHost = serviceProvider.GetService<NetCore.Console.Common.ServiceHost<BatchProcessorService>>())
            {
                serviceHost.Run();                
            }
```

ServiceCommon.Run()

```
public void Run()
        {
            HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.Service<TService>(s =>
                {                    
                    s.AfterStartingService(c =>
                    {
                        _healthChecker.Start();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceSettings.ApiUri))
                        {
                            Startup.ServiceName = serviceSettings.ServiceName;
                            Startup.StatusService = _statusService;                            
                            _apiService = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
                            _apiService.Start();
                            _log.LogInformation($"{serviceSettings.ServiceName} API is running, access health check at {serviceSettings.ApiUri}/healthcheck");
                        }
                    });                                    
                });               
            });
        }
```

Where CreateHostBuilder looks like

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args = null)
        {
            
            return Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseUrls(ServiceSettings.Default.ApiUri)
                        .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
                });
        }
```

And StartUp.ConfigureServices looks like this

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {   
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(ServiceName);
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            }).AddApplicationPart(assembly)
            .AddControllersAsServices();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = $"{ServiceName}",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = $"{ServiceName}"
                });
            });

            var mainRabbitQueue = new MonitoredMessageQueue(new RabbitMessageQueue());
            services.AddSingleton<IMessageQueue>(mainRabbitQueue)
                .AddSingleton<IMessageQueueStats>(mainRabbitQueue)
                .AddTransient<IHeartBeatService, HeartBeatService>()
                .AddSingleton<IStatusService>(StatusService);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using WebHost in a Windows Service? https://www.telerik.com/blogs/.net-core-background-services

Answer (score 2):

The generic host created by `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` inside `s.AfterStartingService(` has new service provider (new dependency injection container). It doesn't have registrations from the service provider created in `Main`.

In .NET Core you don't need Topshelf to run an app as a Windows Service. With `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` nuget you can create a generic host that can be run as a Windows Service, with Kestrel as one of the hosted services.

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .UseWindowsService()
```

You can register your types/services/dependencies in `Startup` and in `ConfigureServices` method of the host builder.

About `UseWindowsService` from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.windowsservicelifetimehostbuilderextensions.usewindowsservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1):

> Sets the host lifetime to WindowsServiceLifetime, sets the Content Root, and enables logging to the event log with the application name as the default source name. This is context aware and will only activate if it detects the process is running as a Windows Service.

Comment: *"In .NET Core you don't need Topshelf to run an app as a Windows Service."* While this may be true, the [excessive complexities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service) associated with deployment under the NuGet package approach far and away leave TopShelf as the more desirable option. Automate all of that, across a wide array of environments? Forget it.